# Why does DateTime.AddMonths(3).AddMonths(3); give a different result than DateTime.AddMonths(6);?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a unit test where the expected result is a DateTime and is set as follows:

```
var expectedResult = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(3).AddMonths(3);
```

After which I have a function that adds quarters to a date:

```
DateTime.AddMonths(3 * numberOfTimes);
```

`numberOfTimes` is in this case 2.

The results differ in date. Today is 31/01/2023, expected result is 30/07/2023 and the function result is 31/07/2023.

I expected the results to be the same because 6 months should have been equal number of days from the starting date. I am curious why this happens. For now I fixed the problem by doing 3 * numberOfTimes in the expectedResult section.

Just out of curiosity why does this happen?

Comment: AddMonth() can only work by rounding the day, you already gave an example of such rounding.  Rounding twice produces a different result.

Comment: Adding 3 month gives you 30th of April because this month has only 30 days. Adding there again 3 month naturally ends up at the 30th of July.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.addmonths?view=net-6.0):

> The `AddMonths` method calculates the resulting month and year, taking
> into account leap years and the number of days in a month, then
> adjusts the day part of the resulting DateTime object. **If the
> resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last
> valid day of the resulting month is used**. For example, March 31st + 1
> month = April 30th, and March 31st - 1 month = February 28 for a
> non-leap year and February 29 for a leap year.

So you get a different result because if you add 6 months it just needs to be checked if 31/07/2023 is a valid DateTime, which it is. For `DateTime.Today.AddMonths(3).AddMonths(3)` it will check first if 31/04/2023 is valid, which is not, so 30/04/2023 is returned, then 3 months are added.

Answer (score 2):

The result can be different because of the way that the date and time is calculated for each method. The `DateTime.AddMonths` method takes into account the number of days in each month and can result in a different day of the month if the original date has a different number of days in the month. For example, adding 3 months to January 31st would result in a different day of the month than adding 6 months to January 31st.